# Get data from child to parent while calling child multiple times in parent in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know i can use a handler function to get data from child to parent component. Like below

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("Hello World");
  const chooseMessage = (message) => {
    setMessage(message);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
      <Child chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const Child = ({ chooseMessage }) => {
  let msg = 'Goodbye';
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => chooseMessage(msg)}>Change    Message</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What if i used `<Child />` multiple times in the same component? how would i handle the data in this case.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("Hello World");
  const chooseMessage = (message) => {
    setMessage(message);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
      <Child chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
      <Child chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
      <Child chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
      <Child chooseMessage={chooseMessage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

What is the best approach to handle this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much context you added to your question, so I'll try to answer it as best as I can.

You want to have multiple information being passed from N number of children to the parent, and (I assume) you cannot create as many states in `Parent` because the number is dynamic. What you want to do is to have an array as the state in the parent, and let each child have an index on that array and let it manipulate the element in the array at that index only.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mclean-f8dzmf?file=/src/Parent.jsx

This is a simple demonstration of what could be done. I only changed `Parent` and did not touch `Child` at all. I'll leave the code below:

`Parent.jsx`

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [messages, setMessage] = useState([
    "Hello 1",
    "Hello 2",
    "Hello 3",
    "Hello 4"
  ]); // ⭐(1)⭐
  const chooseMessage = (message, index) => {
    const newMessages = [...messages]; // ⭐(2)⭐
    newMessages[index] = message;
    setMessage(newMessages);
  }; 
  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message, index) => (
        <h2 key={index}>{message}</h2>
      ))}
      <!-- ⭐(3)⭐ -->
      <Child key="0" chooseMessage={(message) => chooseMessage(message, 0)} />
      <Child key="1" chooseMessage={(message) => chooseMessage(message, 1)} />
      <Child key="2" chooseMessage={(message) => chooseMessage(message, 2)} />
      <Child key="3" chooseMessage={(message) => chooseMessage(message, 3)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

At (1), you can see that the state is an array. In your application, I assume the number of children is going to be dynamic, so start with an empty array and add elements to it as the number of children increases.

At (2), you can see that the `setState` function is a little bit weird. Why am I doing `const newMessages = [...messages]` instead of just `const newMessages = messages`? This is a way to get react to be reactive to the changes in the elements in the array because by default, it does not react to the changes in the elements of an array state, on the changes on the array itself.

At (3), you can see the `chooseMessage` being passed is a little bit different. So for the purpose of the demo, I just set the number of children to 4 and manually set the indices to each child, and created anonymous functions to pass down to the children so the code in `Child` does not have to be changed. In practice, I assume you will need to dynamically create these children through some kind of `.map` function as I did with the `<h2>` tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, At First i also thought array state approach with array of object. but with the index you open a new way to achieve this.